# How can i get someone's profile pic on Discord to edit it using PIL?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, python-imaging-library, discord.py

I'm trying to make some code on python to edit someone's profile pic, but all I've got so far is this:

```
image = ctx.message.author.avatar_url
background = Image.open(image)
```

Apparently that just gets the URL itself, but i need the image itself to edit a picture with PIL. Any insight on how to get it?

Comment: You could use `requests` and request the avatar link, which will likely give you the base64 encoding string which can be then converted to the file type you need and then you can edit it with PIL

Comment: I've checked out requests, but I'm not sure of how to get the encoding, or how to convert that to another file type for that matter. Could you go into a bit more detail?

Comment: Gimme a few mins, I'll see if I can have a quick look at something here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with requests.get(ctx.message.author.avatar_url) as r:
    img_data = r.content
with open('image_name.jpg', 'wb') as handler:
    handler.write(img_data)
```

So I played about with this link a bit:

https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/190434822328418305/6a56d4edf2a82409ffc8253f3afda455.png

And I was able to save my own avatar image (the one I use for my accounts everywhere). I was then able to open the file regularly with the photo viewer app within Pycharm.

After, it would simply become a case of opening the new jpeg file with PIL or pillow instead of trying to open anything from a website, if that makes sense.

You should consider that this will save a file onto your Discord bot server, so this is extremely crude, a malformed or maliciously formed jpeg file could lead to some sort of remote vulnerability.

Furthermore to your comment, if you want the size of the image you download to be bigger, for example, please see the amended link below to solve your problem there:

```
https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/190434822328418305/6a56d4edf2a82409ffc8253f3afda455.png?size=<Number from list [16,32,64,128,256,512,1024,2048]>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Many thanks, it actually worked. Now i just need to tweak the image size a bit

Comment: Well if you are satisfied, please feel free to accept the answer, or if you desire further clarity, please let me know.